# Unable to get @RequiredArgsConstructor working with final Variables

Tags: java, spring, annotations, lombok

I am trying to create a class that looks like:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class ABC {

  @NotNull private final EFG var;
  .
  .
  .

}
```

for some reason, I get a compile time error for this code stating:
`The blank final field var may not have been initialized`

Although, if I was to remove `final` keyword, it compiles perfectly fine.

PS: I have verified that lombok is configured correctly. config includes `lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true`

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you're using IntelliJ did you enabled the annotation processing and installed the lombok plugin?

Comment: Lombok is not actually _running_ on your application. Determine why.

Comment: @CodeMatrix well, IntelliJ is not really complaining. This error occurs when I try to trigger a build using a tool internal to my Company.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- just trying to understand, what makes you think Lombok is not running? well, if I don't mark it final, build goes successful.

Comment: And I bet you that you will not have a non-default constructor.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- can u possibly help with any steps to debug ?

Comment: As @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic has mentioned, I would also doubt that Lombok is not running. Try to add a constructor manually with the `EFG` as a parameter (with the Lombok annotation commented out). This should work, if so, then a problem probably lies with your use of Lombok.

Comment: @Leroy u are right. do u have any suggestion on how I might wanna proceed?

Comment: There are a few avenues you could start with, for example, what build tool manages your dependencies (Mavene/Gradle etc)?

Comment: Does the app build/run ok using Lombok with the above tool (outside of your IDE)? If so, the problem will probably be to do with your company build tool, it will be quite hard for us to debug without any idea of what the build tool your company uses.

Answer (score 0):

I found that configuration was appropriate but sequence in which targets were getting executed was not managed to ensure Lombok code was generated before release begun.

I added `release` target to my `build.xml` with dependency on `delombok`

```
<target name="release" depends="delombok-source,standard-release"/>
```

this automatically ensured a sequence where lombok code was generated before release.